# Is the quasi-equational theory of groups the same as cancellative semigroups?

Tags: lo.logic

Consider the class of groups in the signature {*}. Is the quasi-equational theory of that class axiomatized by the associative law and the left and right cancellative laws?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

Every group satisfies

$$
(xy\approx x'y')\wedge (zy\approx z'y')\wedge (zw\approx z'w')\to (xw\approx x'w')
$$

but this quasi-identity is not derivable from associativity + cancellativity. You can find this in Maltsev's papers *Uber die Einbettug von assoziativen Systemen in Gruppen* parts I and II. In fact, Maltsev proves that the quasi-equational theory of groups in the signature $\{*\}$ is not finitely axiomatizable relative to the theory axiomatized by the associative law and the cancellation laws.